# Увеличить, уменьшить текст нажатием на него

Tags: javascript

Добрый день всех с наступающим!

Помогите решить задачу, а именно создать условие.

Сейчас при нажатии на `Текст 1` он у нас увеличивается и окрашивается, также нужно сделать и для `Текст 2`. Но если один из `span` у нас уже увеличен, то при нажатии на следующий, предыдущий должен принять исходное значение. Таких `span` будет около сотни.

```js
var span = document.querySelector('#big');
span.onclick = function() {
  span.style.fontSize = '13pt';
  span.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  span.style.background = '#D9FFAD';
}
```

```html
<span id="big">Текст 1.</span><br/>
<span id="big">Текст 2.</span><br/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hotfix конечно же. Одинаковый `id` у нескольких элементов использовать нехорошо, поэтому переделал в `class`.

**ES15** (no jQuery)

```js
let span = document.querySelectorAll(".big");

span.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let elem = e.currentTarget;
    elem.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".big").forEach(item => {
      if (item === elem) {
        item.style.fontSize = "13pt";
        item.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        item.style.background = "#D9FFAD";
      } else {
        item.style.fontSize = "";
        item.style.fontWeight = "";
        item.style.background = "";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="big">Текст 1.</span><br>
<span class="big">Текст 2.</span><br>
<span class="big">Текст 3.</span><br>
<span class="big">Текст 4.</span><br>
<span class="big">Текст 5.</span><br>
<span class="big">Текст 6.</span><br>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.big').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.big').forEach(item => item.classList.remove("highlight"));
    this.classList.add("highlight");
  })
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color:red;
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<span class="big">Текст 1.</span><br>
<span class="big">Текст 2.</span><br>
<span class="big">Текст 3.</span><br>
```

Comment: Кто увидит, скажет, что у тя скопировал ответ...)))

Answer (score 4):

Я бы реализовал так. Лучше добавлять-удалять `класс`, чем менять стили через `JS`

```js
const span = document.querySelectorAll('.big');

span.forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
    span.forEach(s => {
      s.classList.remove('active')
    })
    s.classList.add('active');
  })
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-size: 13pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #D9FFAD;
}
```

```html
<span class="big">Текст 1.</span><br/>
<span class="big">Текст 2.</span><br/>
<span class="big">Текст 3.</span><br/>
<span class="big">Текст 4.</span><br/>
<span class="big">Текст 5.</span><br/>
<span class="big">Текст 6.</span><br/>
```